# How to prevent wireless adapter to get automatically disabled when I plug in the LAN cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, lan

I have a new Lenovo W541. At work I have both a cable connection with Proxy and a wifi connection. In my previous laptop I was able to switch from a connection to the other just by disabling and reenabling the proxy. In my new W541 this does not work. If the cable is plugged in, the wifi is automatically disabled. Even if I right click in Wireless Nework Connection and then enable wifi, wifi stays disable. Any suggestion? I searched online for some solutions and one of these was to right click in Wireless Nework Connection, properties, configure,power management and untick " allow the computer to turn off this devise to save power". But it did nothing. Another suggestion was to untick "allowed the wireless LAN radio to be turned off when inactive" within " the program Access connections. I downloaded Access connections (it was not preinstalled), unticked "allowed the wireless LAN radio to be turned off when inactive" but nothing happens. Any other suggestion? I really hate to have to plug and unplug any time the cable to switch connection.

Thanks
A.

Comment: Most laptops have a BIOS option for this. Usually called LAN/WAN Switching.

Comment: I dont find it in my Lenovo W541

Answer (score 0):

You could manually press Fn+F8 and turn ON the Wifi. both Lan and Wifi will ON. If it is not working try to dissable power management on Wifi and turn it On manually by Fn+F8

Comment: It does not work. Also power managent  under property of wifi network as here http://www.stenograph.com/HelpDeskDocs/CaseViewNet/How_to_disable_Power_Management_settings_on_your_WiFi_Adapter.htm is ticked off.